# SnowSQL install Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I followed the linux installation steps [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowsql-install-config.html#linux-install). After installing, attempting to run snowsql results in:

```
snowsql: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

It does NOT include ":Operation not permitted" at the end of the error. The /tmp directory has exec permissions, and I also tried creating my own TMP location as outlined in the second strategy [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/SnowSQL-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libz-so-1-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object-Operation-not-permitted) and the same error occurs. Machine is running ubuntu 16.04.6.

Comment: Everything I'm reading about this suggests that either the `TMP` or `TMPDIR` environment variable needs to be set to a directory that you have access to change permissions. But it seems like you've already done that. Perhaps unix.stackexchange.com might be a better forum for this since it's not really programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article helped out someone I know who was having the same issue:
https://coolaj86.com/articles/using-snowsql-with-docker/

You basically have to set LC_ALL and LANG

If a docker ubuntu image:

```
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
```

If a standard ubuntu EC2/Compute Engine/VM

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

I hope this helps...Rich

p.s. I would also make sure to set TMP to somewhere you know you have full rights on, and of course a clean sudo apt-get -f install

Comment: This is good advice.  Although Ubuntu should be fine, you can also try testing on a different machine just to verify whether it's specific to this particular machine.